# Как быстро и просто сохранить текст в excel из браузерного приложения?

Tags: javascript, html

Читал, что для java есть доп. библиотеки, а вот для скрипта есть какие-то инструменты? Или может запустить из приложения доп. код на джаве написанный?

Comment: быстро и просто - CSV

Answer (score 2):

[Ответ с En SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24081343/4269118):
Работает в IE7+, Firefox и Chrome

```
function fnExcelReport()
{
    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange; var j=0;
    tab = document.getElementById('headerTable'); // id of table

    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {     
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus(); 
        sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    }  
    else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  

    return (sa);
}
```

Просто создаёшь пустой фрейм

```
<iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

И вызываешь функцию

```
<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();"> EXPORT </button>
```

**PS**

Учитесь пользоваться поиском!

Comment: я обычно сайта четыре, пять пролистываю, не нашел по теме. Благодарю! Изучаю!)

Comment: Млин, никак не пойму как указать для записи то что мне нужно. Вставляю функцию в main.js. По выполнению вылазит ошибка : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null